# What is Best Practice for C# ADO.NET database connection and parameterized query?

Tags: c#

I am learning C# as of now. I have copied the below C# code from a forum.

I understand what the coding does and its syntax. I need to know whether the coding follows best practices for C#.

```
connectionString = "Data Source=S9; " +
                   "Initial Catalog=Hp;" +
                   " Integrated Security=SSPI";
sql = "Insert into tt(cr,TimeSpent_Min,Date,Empid) values (@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4)";

connection.Open();
command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", textBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", textBox2.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", textBox3.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", textBox4.Text);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.Dispose();
connection.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Successfully Inserted ");
```

Edit for question clarity : The reason I'am asking the question is in most online forums they provide the above general structure to connect with the database. But the explanation and best practices are not availabe

Comment: If you want a code review, you might want to go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Optimized for what? Speed? Memory? Maintainability? Scalability? There's a lot of give and take depending on what you're aiming for. This seems like a much better fit for Code Review than SO.

Comment: If you don't know what you are optimising for, you really shouldn't be worrying about it. Optimise when there is a problem.

Comment: You should look up C#'s "using" statement (the Dispose version).  I'm also curious how you went from `connetionString = "[a connection string]'` to `connection.Open();`

Comment: And [stop using `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've supplied could be improved a bit.  You may want to consider something like the following.  It uses the C# `using` construct to ensure that disposable objects, such as the SqlConnection object and the SqlCommand objects are closed and disposed when you've finished using them.

Also, though I haven't shown it here, you may want to validate your textbox contents prior to stuffing those into parameter values.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

...

string connectionString = "Data Source=S9; " +
                   "Initial Catalog=Hp; " +
                   "Integrated Security=SSPI";
string sql = "Insert into tt(cr,TimeSpent_Min,Date,Empid) values (@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4)";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", textBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", textBox2.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", textBox3.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", textBox4.Text);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
MessageBox.Show("Successfully Inserted");
```

**It's important to note** that using the `Parameters.AddWithValue()` method can be troublesome because the library makes assumptions about your parameters that may or may not be true.  It is safer to build individual `Parameter` objects and add them to your `Parameters` collection.

#### EDIT

I was thinking about my answer to your question, and it seems obvious that there will be problems here with the `Parameters.AddWithValue()` calls, and here's why: 
 your query inserts 4 values into table `TT`: `[cr]`, `[TimeSpent_Min]`, `[Date]`, and `[EmpID]`, and they're probably not all nvarchar fields.  Looking at the field names, it's hard to infer any datatype for `[cr]` - possibly `varchar`, `nvarchar`, `char`, or `nchar`.  But `[TimeSpent_Min]` seems like it might be either `int`, `time`, or `datetime`.  Your field `[Date]` might be `date` or `datetime`.  And finally, your field `[EmpID]` might be type `varchar`, `char`, or `int`.

Of course, these are all just guesses. It's impossible for me to infer the datatypes of these values from their name.  In your case, by using `Parameters.AddWithValue()`, you're asking the .NET framework to make an inference about their datatype by matching it to the type of the parameter being passed into the `AddWithValue()` call.

You're passing in `Textbox.Text` values, which are, of course, type string.  Therefore, all of these parameters will be created with type `nvarchar`, because that's what the framework methods are coded to match a .NET string.  If the database fields aren't actually `nvarchar`, then there could be problems.

There is a better way.  As an example, **ASSUMING** that your parameters are the following types, here's how you can populate the `Parameters` collection more accurately:

```
Field            Parameter  Datatype
---------------  ---------  -------------
[cr]             @p1        nvarchar(100)
[TimeSpent_Min]  @p2        int
[Date]           @p3        datetime
[EmpID]          @p4        int
```

Code to go with this could be as follows:

```
// convert textbox values to proper datatypes
string parmP1Value = textBox1.Text;
int parmP2Value = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
DateTime parmP3Value = DateTime.Parse(textBox3.Text);
int parmP4Value = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);

// create and load parameters
command.Parameters.AddRange(new[]
                            {
                                new SqlParameter
                                {
                                    ParameterName = "@p1",
                                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                                    Size = 100,
                                    Value = parmP1Value
                                },
                                new SqlParameter
                                {
                                    ParameterName = "@p2",
                                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                                    Value = parmP2Value
                                },
                                new SqlParameter
                                {
                                    ParameterName = "@p3",
                                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime,
                                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                                    Value = parmP3Value
                                },
                                new SqlParameter
                                {
                                    ParameterName = "@p4",
                                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                                    Value = parmP4Value
                                }
                            }
                           );
```